# What is the meaning of file tab text colors in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

Since a few days ago, I've noticed a difference in colors in the file tabs.

Basically normal is white, other things are colorful such as green or blue. My guess is that these are affected by Git or something.

[image]

There are no error or warning in that source code; what does the difference in colors mean?

Comment: White means that you have not modified a file since your last commit. Blue means you have modified a file since your last commit. Green means you added/staged a file to Git for the first time.

Comment: @TechRando Thank you. After I saw your comment , I search these things finally I found it!

Comment: @TechRando This is correct; perhaps post it as an answer so OP can mark it accepted.

Answer (score 1):

White means that you **have not** modified a file since your last commit. Blue means you **have** modified a file since your last commit. Green means you added/staged a file to Git for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

Before creating or adding the project to git, all files and folders are displayed in **white** color. However, after adding the project to git, the files and folders are color-coded to indicate their status:

1. **White**: Files/folders that have already been added to git and are currently up to date.
2. **Blue**: Files/folders that have been added to git but have local modifications (need to be committed to update the remote repository).
3. **Green**: Files/folders that have just been added to git and haven't been committed or pushed yet.
4. **Red**: Files/folders that have been removed from git but still exist in the local directory.
5. **Yellow**: Files/folders that are ignored by git and will not be tracked in version control.
6. **Grey**: Files/folders that are not being considered or are not relevant to the current git operation (not fully sure about their status).

These color codes provide a visual representation of the git status of each file or folder in the project.